# How can I suppress Google Chrome's virus warning page?

Tags: google-chrome, malware, security-warning

On some sites, Google Chrome gives the error

> Warning: Something's Not Right Here!"
>   (web address) contains malware. Your computer might catch a virus if you visit this site.

Every time I see this error, I click the "proceed anyway" link.

Is there a way to suppress this message and enter the site directly?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Chrome privacy/security help file](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=99020),

1. Click the wrench icon [image: wrench icon] on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Options** (**Preferences** on Mac and Linux; **Settings** on Chrome OS).
3. Click the **Under the Hood** tab and find the "Privacy" section.
4. Deselect the "Enable phishing and malware protection" checkbox.

All formatting original.

Note that this will disable the warning for **all** sites. I think it's a bad idea, but it's the correct answer to your technical question.

Comment: At first glance, it seems like an incorrect method because intuition says that the desired result is to leave the protection enabled to stay safe, but skip the warning. But since skipping the warning bypasses the protection in the first place, they are effectively the same thing, therefore like Lord Torgamus said, this answer is indeed correct for the desired result (*> Every time I see this error, I click the "proceed anyway" link.*). `;-)` Sadly, there is not yet a way to add a site to a whitelist to keep the protection but ignore it for certain sites (ie, trust Google’s results or nothing).